# SQL - ORACLE change rows to column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some table

```
1 | 2 | test,test| 4
```

I need a query to return this table in this format:

```
1 | 2 | test | 4
1 | 2 | test | 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for giving you the links. But, might help you.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:419593546543

Answer (score 0):

```
with src as
(
        select  '1' col0,  '2' col1, 'test1,test2'   col2 from dual union all
        select '11' col0, '22' col1, 'test11,test22' col2 from dual
)
, explode as
(
        select  col0
        ,       col1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 1) as col2_1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 2) as col2_2
        --      if there is more add more...
        from    src
)
select col0, col1, col2_1 from explode where col2_1 is not null union all
select col0, col1, col2_2 from explode where col2_2 is not null 
order by col0, col1, col2_1
;

1   2   test1
1   2   test2
11  22  test11
11  22  test22
```

An example for five values:

```
with src as
(
        select  '1'  col0,   '2' col1, 'test1,test2'                        col2 from dual union all
        select '11'  col0,  '22' col1, 'test11,test22'                      col2 from dual union all
        select '111' col0, '222' col1, 'test31,test32,test33,test34,test35' col2 from dual
)
, explode as
(
        select  col0
        ,       col1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 1) as col2_1
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 2) as col2_2
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 3) as col2_3
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 4) as col2_4
        ,       regexp_substr(col2, '\w+', 1, 5) as col2_5
        --      if there is more add more...
        from    src
)
select col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_5 from explode where col2_1 is not null union all
select col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_5 from explode where col2_2 is not null union all
select col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_5 from explode where col2_3 is not null union all
select col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_5 from explode where col2_4 is not null union all
select col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_5 from explode where col2_5 is not null
order by col0, col1, col2_1, col2_2, col2_3, col2_4, col2_4, col2_5
;

1   2   test1   test2           
1   2   test1   test2           
11  22  test11  test22          
11  22  test11  test22          
111 222 test31  test32  test33  test34  test35
111 222 test31  test32  test33  test34  test35
111 222 test31  test32  test33  test34  test35
111 222 test31  test32  test33  test34  test35
111 222 test31  test32  test33  test34  test35
```

Comment: ok thx but sometimes I have more values in one rows sometimes 3 sometimes 5

Comment: @JohnRambo You have to repeat the "regexp_substr" function in the "explode" section as many times as it is needed. You can give more just in case...

Comment: Yes I understandt this sample but I nedd dynamic SQL but sometimes user write 2 values meybe 6. 2 and 6 is dynamic values I don now what user write :)

Comment: 1) If you think user can give 20 values, repeat it for 20. It is static unfortunately. The same as the links from a one other answer.
2) you can use: regexp_count(col2, ',')

Comment: Oki thx the_slh regexp_count(col2, ',') is very good form my .